# Change position of UIImageView when Animating in NSArray

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview

So I've seen a whole bunch of resources an answers to similar questions regarding how to change the position of a UIImageView, which can be done like this:

```
myUIImageView.center = CGPointMake(myImage_X, myImage_Y);
```

But I can not get this to work when I have my UIImageView animating.

I start my animation like this:

```
 myUIImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],nil];

[myUIImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
myUIImageView.animationDuration = 1.0;
[myUIImageView startAnimating];
```

Then try to move it with the line of code above... which didn't work.
Then I tried this after setting it as a property and synthesising it:

```
[myUIImageView setFrame:CGRectMake( 10, 
                                    10, 
                                    myUIImageView.frame.size.width,   
                                    myUIImageView.frame.size.height
                                  )];
```

But it doesn't move the image :(

Currently my image is animating on the spot. But I want it to initially change position (set the coords to top of the screen), then have it fall in the Y direction. Am I doing something silly?

Comment: myUIImageView = CGPointMake(myImage_X, myImage_Y); and myUIImageView = 0.1; what you think to do with that?

Comment: Sounds like an auto layout problem. If your image view is using auto layout, you should not set any frames to move it, you should modify the constraints.

Comment: @NekakKinich sorry I typed it wrong. Missed out .animationDuration.

Comment: @rdelmar Looks like you were right. I disabled size classes and auto layout and it's working fine. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: It would be better to leave auto layout on, and move the view like I said.

Comment: @rdelmar I'm not completely sure how to implement it that way. Also, I'm currently building a storyboard for each screensize. The correct storyboard is then loaded based on which device it's being used on, so I think auto layout and size classes are redundant in this situation.

Comment: Well, you don't animating it. And can you explain what that line means: "myUIImageView = CGPointMake(myImage_X, myImage_Y);" ?
Anyway, you just need to wrap it within [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{ [your animation block with the frame] }];

Comment: @oren It does animate it and CGPointMake places the UIImageView's centers on new coordinates. If I understand your comment correctly.